# Share unnamed semaphore between processes in Mac OS

Tags: process, semaphore, mach

I'm trying to share a unnamed mach semaphore between two processes.
I can create one and wait on it in the same process.

```
semaphore_t semaphore = 0;
mach_error_t err = semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), &semaphore, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, 0);
...
semaphore_wait(semaphore);
```

But I want to send it to another process (of which I only have the mach_port_t) and then let it semaphore_signal my own process.

I already tried things like:

```
mach_port_allocate(target, MACH_PORT_RIGHT_RECEIVE, targetSemaphore)
mach_port_insert_right(target, targetSemaphore, semaphore, MACH_MSG_TYPE_COPY_SEND)
```

Which will yield an error because the port name already exists in the target process or a "unknown failure" if I don't allocate it in the target process.

And even:

```
mach_msg_send
mach_msg_receive
```

But I can't even get a port right form one process to anther to send anything.

What am I doing wrong and is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
mach_port_extract_right
```

is correct way, instead of:

```
mach_port_insert_right
```

Then doing this, will do the job:

```
semaphore_t semaphore = 0;
mach_error_t err = semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), &semaphore, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, 0);

err = mach_port_allocate(target, MACH_PORT_RIGHT_RECEIVE, &receivePort);

mach_msg_type_name_t type;
semaphore_t sendPort = 0;
err = mach_port_extract_right(target, receivePort, MACH_MSG_TYPE_MAKE_SEND, &sendPort, &type);

//Send semaphore using port
mach_msg_send(&msg.header);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Unfortunately, your code example is incomplete (what is `target`? what is `receivePort`? where do you actually send the `semaphore`? etc.) Can you share a fully working example? That would be amazing!